# Is it possible to use a XOF function as csrng?

Tags: random-number-generator, xof

Let's say we "seed" a xof function (eg. SHAKE256) with x cryptographically random bytes (enough so that they can't be bruteforced), could said function be used as a cryptographically secure random generator? If so, when should the function be reseeded and start the process over?

Comment: You really don't want to use XOFs or stream ciphers or similar constructions for CSPRNGs. Just use a standardised CSPRNG like the [NIST AES-CTR DRBG](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-90a/rev-1/final) (and if you really want to, replace "aes-ctr" with your stream cipher)

Comment: @SEJPM Maybe consider pointing out what DRBGs have that XOFs don't?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but it may answer your question.

Comment: @SEJPM Why? I guess backtracking, but with short lived RNGs that's not a critical property for random number generation. (Unless secrets don't get erased from memory. But, regardless, the output may be a secret that needs erasing just as well.)